# Do I need a custom field for a db field alias?

Tags: php, xml, sql, fields

When viewing an individual record, I'm using a calculated field from a sql query to display as a read only field in my form. However I'm unable to get it to display (no error, just blank). Curious, do I need a custom form to display this?

/forms/myform.xml

```
        <field
            name="current_age"
            type="text"
            readonly="true"
            label="DOB_AGE"
            description="DOB_AGE_DESC"
            size="40"
            default="0"
            />
```

fields/myfield.php

```
    protected function getOptions()
{
    $db    = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    $query->select('d.*,(YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.dancer_birthdate)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(d.dancer_birthdate,5)) AS d.current_age,c.title as category');
    $query->from('#__registration_dancers as d');
    $query->leftJoin('#__categories as c on d.catid=c.id');
    // Retrieve only published items
    $query->where('d.published = 1');
    $db->setQuery((string) $query);
    $messages = $db->loadObjectList();
    $options  = array();

    if ($messages)
    {
        foreach ($messages as $message)
        {
            $options[] = JHtml::_('select.option', $message->dancer_id, $message->dancer_name .
                                  ($message->catid ? ' (' . $message->category . ')' : ''), $message->dancer_birthdate,
                                $message->studio_id, $message->dateadded, $message->datemodified, 
                                  $message->current_age, $message->published);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From all of my research and testing, I don't think this is possible. I ended up solving my quandary with a custom field instead of an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as far as I know, SQL can only be used with [SQL form field](https://docs.joomla.org/SQL_form_field_type) and this generates dropdown list. So to just show some value from DB, you have to create custom field.

**Old answer**

Your need to add the field path to `myform.xml` parent `<fieldset>` to load your custom fields. This is only needed if you haven't added your custom fieldpath in PHP.

```
<fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/<component name>/models/fields">
```

To add field path with PHP, so you don't need to add it in every form XML, use (for example in your component main file):

```
JForm::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');
```

And in `myform.xml` set `type` as your new form field.

```
    <field
        name="current_age"
        type="myfield" <----- custom field type
        readonly="true"
        label="DOB_AGE"
        description="DOB_AGE_DESC"
        size="40"
        default="0"
        />
```

And your field class should be named `JFormFieldmyfield`. Just to make sure you have correct `class` name.

Further reading [Joomla! Docs: Creating a custom form field type](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isn't what I was asking. I know how to create custom fields but I'm trying to avoid doing that in this case because all I'm doing is displaying a database field that I calculated in the query itself. What I'm trying to answer is whether a custom field is *required* when referencing database field aliases: you can see in my query, "current_age" doesn't exist as an actual field - it was calculated in the query: (YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(d.dancer_birthdate)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5)<RIGHT(d.dancer_birthdate,5)) AS d.current_age,

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: You are persistent but your edited answer still does not address my question. I am no trying to use the sql form field (I recognize this only created a drop down field)- the sql I posted was from my fields/myform.phpfile, which I believe, retrieves the content to display in the form so I'm not sure why an alias here wouldn't work...

Third time's the charm?

Comment: Okay. I think I get it now :) Did you set myfield as your field type? In question it is text, which is wrong.

Comment: If I'm trying to reference a database field alias - not a custom field, what should it be? When I'm referencing a standard database field, it *can* be just "text".

Comment: If it is `text` then you must get that db alias in model, so that your form data has that field.